# Xamarin Live Player not working on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

I have created a Xamarin.Forms application using .NET standard library. I am trying to run iOS application on my iOS device using Xamarin Live Player application but I am always getting the error 
"The type or namespace 'Xamarin' could not be found in global namespace"
I have tried to update Xamarin.Forms as some links suggested but still no fruitful.
Here is the screenshot of error that I am getting. [image: Xamarin Live Player error in iPhone 6 plus]

Please help me with running application on my iOS device. My device is iPhone 6 Plus and iOS version is 11.4.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Xamarin Live Player is not available on iOS, as mentioned here:

[Xamarin Live Player](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations)

This is one of its limitations.

> Limitations There are some limitations on the things Xamarin Live
>   Player can run, including the items below:
>
> **iOS**
>
> *Live Player is not available for iOS.*